# C++ metaprogramming vs inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, metaprogramming

I was wondering if there's a particular advantage to use metaprogramming (i.e. templates) against inheritance in C++ when we can achieve the same functional goal.

For example we could do something (I'm just coming up with such examples...):

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
 public:
   //bla bla
 private:
  T data;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};
```

With typetraits we can further restrict to a particular class of objects. However i guess we could do something very similar with inheritance:

```
class Base {
 //bla bla
};

class Der1 : public Base {
 //bla bla
};

//.
//.
//.
class DerN : public Base {
 //bla bla
};

class Node {
 public:
  //bla bla
 private:
  Base* data;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};
```

What's the advantage in a case like this one? What's the crucial factor in choosing one or the other when we can use both to achieve the same thing?

Comment: What about `Node<int>`?

Comment: Obviously using templates you just need one class. Except when you need template specialization

Comment: with templates you dont have runtime polymorphism. In this case, you dont need it, so I would go for templates

Comment: @anderas Just wrap it... you can find a solution for that.

Comment: in reality a mixture of both is called for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many questions of this kind, the "crucial factor" depends on the application of the code.

What's more important, compilation times, code complexity, or speed of execution?

- If you intention is to make the compile-times faster (due to project size, or older-build servers), you want to avoid templates, every code-change to a template will rebuild all source-files the template-headers are included in.
- If your concerned about execution times, templates often allow for you to produce code that the **compiler can optimise** specifically for the types in question, however inheritance allows **you to optimise** the code specifically for each type (with the added vtable-lookup times). Thus you'd need to benchmark trail code for both.
- If your concerned with code-complexity (**and that for most modern applications is the biggest priority**) It depends on both the skill of other developers on the project, as well as the number of template specialisations you'll need.

In regard to the last point, gauging that requires a complex understanding of the task beyond the scope of this question, however my advice is simple; if you would require anywhere near as many specialisations as you have types - use inheritance instead. For something like your example node-tree, inherited types will provide a much better solution for the average developer to work with, if however you needed a "works for everything" method or function (such as a stream `<<` operator) using a template would be a better recourse.

## tl;dr

Unless you have a specific processing/memory overhead to worry about, use the one that creates the smallest-amount of code. Aim for *clean, clear and easy to read*.

Comment: Nice answer, with "smallest amount of code" do you mean "written code" or "generated" (assembly) code?

Comment: Written code - if you find yourself worried about binary product size (IE: embedded devices) you'll generally be working with C rather than C++. Or rather, it is better to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The two concepts are unrelated.

Inheritance merely gives runtime polymorphism - concrete actions may be applied to any object provided that it *is a* base object.

While generic programming allows one to code in terms of general concepts - i.e. apply this general operation to these objects of unrelated type.

The use cases are distinct, and often complimentary. The CRTP pattern is an example - generic programming is used to provide an implementation of an inheritable interface.

> With typetraits we can further restrict to a particular class of objects. However i guess we could do something very similar with inheritance:

Not at compile time, you can't. One of the major disadvantages of inheritance - particularly when seeking to restrict or specialise operations based on type is that this must be done at runtime - which means what would have been compiler errors with generic programming now become runtime errors that present themselves to users.

Compiler errors are good - the rot stops before code is checked in. Runtime errors are evil. They are are (at least) two orders of magnitude more costly to fix and they make you (or your firm) look bad.

Answer (score 0):

Templates:

- Compile-time mechanism (i.e. no run-time overhead)
- No Polymorphism: Node and Node are completely different objects, without any relationship (so you cannot convert from one type to the other)

Inheritance is typically a more flexible approach. It really depends on the behavior you need to achieve.

Comment: Imagine a situation where you have equivalent functional behaviour, I'm talking about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Some really generalizing statement: Performance-wise you have a larger compile time with templates and a larger runtime with dynamic polymorphism.

It is sometimes structually more complex to work with templates. That is why even some performance-optimized pieces of software are not using templates all the way. However, I have seen some optimization software that uses templates as much as possible and is incredible fast.